# Javascript multiline string issue

Tags: javascript, string, multiline

My code is:

```js
let testStr = "Asdfads";
let htmlStr = `<script>${ testStr }</script>`; // but it works with: <div>${ testStr }</div>
console.log(htmlStr);
```

It returns me an error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal

What do I do wrong? I run it on the latest Chrome.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @user202729, it doesn't work in the snippet also! I'm using MacOS X 10.12

Comment: issue is closing tag `<\/script>`

Comment: @epascarello So, template literal is actually a modern `document.write` ..?

Comment: @Teemu Has nothing to do with document.write..... A normal string would have the same issue.

Comment: @epascarello Indeed, I've never noticed this before.

Comment: `\`<script>${ testStr }<\/script>\``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your `"</script>"`: it ends the script element in which it is embedded (hence the "unterminated template literal").

A solution is to write it in another form, for example

```
`</` + "script>"
```

or

```
let htmlStr = `<script>${ testStr }</${"script"}>`;
```

or

```
let htmlStr = `<script>${ testStr }</\script>`;
```

(any other construct not containing `"</script>"` would be fine).

This isn't about templates or strings: this is read when the HTML page is read, long before the javascript is even parsed.

Comment: But why does it work with the: `<div>${ testStr }</div>`? It's also unescaped.

Comment: Because HTML tags need to be matched.

Comment: @JavaRunner the problem is **only** with </script> because that's what tells the page parser where the script ends, before the script is event parsed.

Comment: So why not give a solution for a template literal instead of telling them they have to use `""`?

Comment: @epascarello because it's painful to write template literals in SO answers... But I'll try

Comment: LOL, the solution for writing the answer to escape the `/` is the same to post `\`` in stackoverflow.

Comment: Basically anyway such that `</script>` is not a substring of  the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Closing script tags should be escaped.

```
let htmlStr = `<script>${ testStr }<\/script>`;
```

would work

Comment: Not really. Just the </script> because it is read *before* he Javascript is even parsed.

Comment: Yeah, I did mean to say closing script tags. Good spot. I see you answered just before me anyway so they have the answer.